# Convert String to Integer value using Lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

How can I convert a `String` into `int` value using Java 8 lambdas ?

I have tried to convert the `String` into `IntStream` like this, and apply a method `mapToInt` on it but it gives error,

```
    int x = "582564625".chars().boxed().mapToInt(???)
```

What i really want is, to convert "582564625" into `int` value and store it in variable `x`.

in above line, what should I replace `???` with ?

Comment: Wht do you want to achieve exactly? What should the value of `x` be?

Comment: What's the point? Just use `Integer.parseInt`.

Comment: `List<Integer> list = Stream.of("12345").map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());` But why?

Comment: I want to convert the string `"582564625"` to an int value and assign it to `x`, i know i can use `Integer.parseInt` but I am trying to do in Java 8, just learning lambdas.

Comment: @Magnamag, you are converting it into a list of integer, not an `int` value.

Comment: @bhuvesh That would be abuse of lambda IMO. There are other stuffs that you can do with lambdas if you want to learn them.

Comment: Lambdas aren't useful for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [sprinter’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28308224/2711488) provides a solution which works in a sequential context, the provided function violates the [associativity contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Associativity) which the [specification of `reduce`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) mandates. This will fail as soon as you start using [`parallel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#parallel--) streams.

You can’t provide a correct associative function using `int` values if you consider what happens if you try to process the input value `1000`. You can’t process `10` and `00` individually and join their results afterwards.

To solve this you need a value which carries both, the actual numerical value and the associated number of digits. You could use `reduce` with such a value type if the value type is immutable or at least treated like immutable. This would imply possible instance creations for every operation, therefore I prefer the alternative, using [Mutable Reduction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) where we use a mutable container holding the current value and number of digits. We can simply use an `int[]` array of length two if we don’t want to introduce a new `class` for this:

```
int iValue = numberString.chars()
    .map(n -> Character.digit(n, 10))
    .parallel()
    .collect(()->new int[]{0,1},
             (ia, v) -> { ia[0]=ia[0]*10 + v; ia[1]*=10; },
             (ia1, ia2) -> { ia1[0]=ia1[0]*ia2[1]+ia2[0]; ia1[1]*=ia2[1]; })[0];
```

The actual value is carried in the first element and the number of digits is carried in the second in form of a factor which is required when two containers have to be merged after concurrent computation.

So the first function `()->new int[]{0,1}` implements the `Supplier` for a new container which will be used by each thread before calling the second function which adds a value to the container using the know `x=x*10+y` pattern and raises the number of digits by multiplying the factor (which is intially `1`) by `10`.

The third function will join two containers and will be called once two threads finished their work. It will update the first container with the values of the second using the factors which represent the number of digits.

---

After all, this is indeed an interesting question to demonstrate principles of stream processing even if `Integer.parseInt` is simpler and always faster for all `String` lengths for which the value still fits into in `int`. It should be noted that this example does not check for any error condition but simply produce nonsense for illegal characters.

Answer (score 3):

Java 8 streams are intended to be used for streams of values, not single values. In your case the original `String` and the `int` are single values so this is not a good use case for a stream.

If instead you wanted to convert your String to its digit set to, for example, sum the digits that might well be a use of streams.

```
numberString.chars().map(n -> Character.digit(n, 10)).sum();
```

But just to answer your question explicitly, if you particularly wanted to convert to digits and then convert back to an int you could do:

```
int n = numberString.chars()
    .map(n -> Character.digit(n, 10))
    .reduce(0, (n, d) -> n * 10 + d);
```

But that is probably about as pointless as it looks!

Comment: It is worse than pointless.   `(n, d) -> n * 10 + d` is not an associative function and thus violates the contract of `reduce`.   All it would take to break this implementation is for somebody to say "hey, let's make this faster with .parallel()".

Comment: @Misha: you are right. [I added an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28318238/2711488) which shows how to do it right. It’s of course still as pointless if you ever consider it for production code, but I think, it’s possible to learn something out of it…

Comment: Yes you are, of course, correct. I should have made that point in my answer. However I feel @Misha's answer makes it even clearer than mine (and correctly) that this is a bit of a pointless intellectual exercise. The most important point I made was probably in the first sentence.